# Android Camera2API get current exposure time during preview

Tags: android, camera, controls

I have an application built on top of the example below:
https://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Basic/src/com.example.android.camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.html

Since the AE is on, the exposure time changes with light conditions in the scene. I need to find the current exposure time. Can anyone share some code snipped for this?

Answer (score 0):

[CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION) is Exposure time.

you can check [CONTROL_AE_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#CONTROL_AE_STATE) in CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback. (line286@Camera2BasicFragment.java)

AE_STATE changes like this.

INACTIVE->SEARCHING->CONVERGED(or FLASH_REQUIRED,LOCKED)

```
                case STATE_PREVIEW: {
                Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                if(aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {/*get EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION*/} 
                break;
```

Comment: exposure compensation is an adjustment ON TOP of the current exposure and is NOT exposure itself. Exposure compensation can make your images brighter or darker compared to no compensation. It is used to modify convergence level of autoexposure only.